# Computing volume by cross section method.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The base of the solid below is the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the $x$-axis,the graph of y = $\sqrt{x}$ and the line $ x = 3 $. Find the volume of the solid.

Each cross-section of S perpendicular to the x-axis is a square with one side in the$ xy$-plane.

Comment: The limits of integration of all your slices will be the value of $ \ x \ $ where $ \ \sqrt{x} \ $ meets the $ \ x-$ axis and $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ $ .  The infinitesimal volume of each slice is the area of a square of side $ \ \sqrt{x} \ $ and a thickness $ \ dx \ $ .

Comment: The solid below? What do you mean?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Actually i don't understand this section from the professor at all. So first lets deal with the limits of integration. You said it will be the value of $ x $ where $ \sqrt{x} $ meets with $ x$-axis and $ x = 3 $. So i set $ \sqrt{x} $ equal to $ 3 $ and then find $x$ ?

Comment: @CameronBuie That's what's written in the book. Actually the question is 4 parts and it said "The base of each solid below" but i just wrote the first part which is the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the graph of the relevant portion of $f(x) = \sqrt x$:

[image]

And here is a pic of the resulting solid with the same portion shaded for comparison:

[image]

Imagine taking slices of this solid as you move along the x-axis from 0 to 3. At each point x, the cross-sectional area $A(x)$ is $(\sqrt x)^2$. Now integrate $A(x)$ over the interval $[0, 3]$, so $V = \int _0^3(\sqrt x)^2dx = \int_0^3 xdx = \frac 9 2$

Comment: Do i have to draw the graph ? In my case, here i don't know what $ y = \sqrt{x} $ looks like.

Comment: Why $ A(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2 $ ? I know that the area of the square is $ s^2 $ but why is the side equal to $ \sqrt{x} $ ?

Comment: You should know what $y = \sqrt x$ looks like now because I drew the graph for you. However, if you did not know what it looks like before then yes, you should definitely draw it out to get a feel for it because that is a very basic function that you should be very familiar with. As far as do you have to draw the graph for your homework: I don't know. Probably not, unless the instructions say so. I just drew that for you to provide clarity and understanding. Hope it helped. If I answered your question can you accept my solution an answer?

Comment: The problem is telling you that each cross-section is a SQUARE, and we know that one of the square's side's length is equal to the height of $f(x)$ at whatever particular point we are concerned with at that moment. If ONE of the square's sides is $f(x) = \sqrt x$ then ALL FOUR of the square's sides have that same length. Thus at any point $x$ each side has length $\sqrt x$ and the square's area is $(\sqrt x)^2$.

Comment: This is the pertinent part of the problem: "a square with one side in the xy-plane." We know the length of that one side: at $x$ it is $\sqrt x$. Thus we know the area of that cross-section at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are given cross-sections perpendicular to the x-axis, your limits of integration and integrand will be in terms of x:

$V=\int_0^3 A(x) \;dx=\int_0^3(s(x))^2\;dx$ where, as noted in the first comment above, $s(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Why the limits of the integration are from 0 to 3 ?

Comment: @Tennisman These are the values of x in the region which forms the base of the solid.  (If we were using cross-sections perpendicular to the y-axis, we would use y-values instead.)

Comment: Why $ s(x) = \sqrt{x} $ ?

Comment: @Tennisman Since you're taking slices perpendicular to the x-axis, the bottom side of the square is a vertical line segment with lower edge on the x-axis and top edge on the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do the same question but the cross section will be perpendicular to the x-axis and is an equilateral triangle with one side in the xy-plane and other part where the cross section will be perpendicular to the y-axis and is a square with one side in the xy plane